# Most efficient way to find and replace in R

Tags: r, join, replace, merge, vlookup

I have a dataframe key and a column in a dataframe that needs to be remapped according to the key.

```
IDhex=c("asdj23","kjh23s")
IDHuman=c("Label1","Label2")

IDKey=data.frame(IDhex,IDHuman)
```

`MasterDF$UserID` has a thousands of entries of either `asdj23`, `kjh23s` or `''` (empty).
I need to find an replace this column according to the mapping from `IDkey`. I need a coding solution that is INDEPENDENT OF IDKEY size. There will be a loop that takes in different keys that are 2xn in size.

Comment: What do you mean by "remaped?" You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output.

Comment: Make a new data frame, a look-up table. Then `merge` or `left_join`.

Comment: Typo:  `IDHuman != IDhuman`. And IDKey is not a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but you could look at gsub() which lets you search using a pattern or regex and replace with a designated value.

For instance:

```
x <- rep(c("a","b"), 10)
x
```

> [1] "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b" "a" "b"

```
match_pattern <- "a"
replace_pattern <- "fixed"
gsub(match_pattern, replace_pattern, x)
```

> [1] "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"
>   [15] "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"     "fixed" "b"

Comment: Thanks Gabriel FGM